# Не отрабатывает enum converter в spring-data

Tags: java, spring-data, enum

Такая проблема, у меня в коде не отрабатывает конвертер для перечислений, причем делаю его не у первый раз, но на новом проекте не хочет отрабатывать.
Перечисления такие:

Раз:

```java
    public enum ImageSize {
        HIGH("h", 1200),
        LOW("l", 450),
        PREVIEW("p", 160),
        NONE("n", null);
    
        @Getter
        final String dbValue;
    
        @Getter
        final Integer sideLength;
    
        ImageSize(String dbValue, Integer sideLength) {
            this.dbValue = dbValue;
            this.sideLength = sideLength;
        }
```

Два:

```java
    public enum ImageType {
        OBSERSE("o"),
        REVERSE("r"),
        PACKAGING("p"),
        SPRITE("s");
    
        @Getter
        private final String dbValue;
    
        ImageType(String dbValue) {
            this.dbValue = dbValue;
        }
    }
```

Далее, сущность вот такая:

```java
    @Table(name = "image")
    @Entity
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ToString(exclude = "content")
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @IdClass(Image.PK.class)
    public class Image implements Persistable<Image.PK>, Persistence {
        @Id
        @JoinColumn(name = "catalog_num_code")
        private String catalogNumCode;
    
        @Id
        @Column(name = "type", nullable = false, length = 1)
        @Convert(converter = ImageTypeConverter.class)
        private ImageType type;
    
        @Id
        @Column(name = "size", nullable = false, length = 1)
        @Convert(converter = ImageSizeConverter.class)
        private ImageSize size;
    
        @Lob
        @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.BinaryType")
        @Column(name = "content", columnDefinition="bytea")
        private byte[] content;
    
        @UpdateTimestamp
        @Column(name = "modify_At")
        private Timestamp modifyDate;
    
        @Override
        public PK getId() {
            return new Image.PK(catalogNumCode, type, size);
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean isNew() {
            return false;
        }
    
        @NoArgsConstructor
        @AllArgsConstructor
        @Setter
        @Getter
        @EqualsAndHashCode
        public static class PK implements Serializable {
            private String catalogNumCode;
            private ImageType type;
            private ImageSize size;
        }
    }
```

И, соответственно, вот такие конвертеры:

Раз:

```java
@Converter
public class ImageTypeConverter implements AttributeConverter<ImageType, String> {
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(ImageType type) {
        if (type == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return type.getDbValue();
    }

    @Override
    public ImageType convertToEntityAttribute(String value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return Stream.of(ImageType.values())
                .filter(type -> type.getDbValue().equals(value))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
    }
}
```

Два:

```java
    @Converter
    public class ImageSizeConverter implements AttributeConverter<ImageSize, String> {
        @Override
        public String convertToDatabaseColumn(ImageSize size) {
            if (size == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return size.getDbValue();
        }
    
        @Override
        public ImageSize convertToEntityAttribute(String value) {
            if (value == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return Stream.of(ImageSize.values())
                    .filter(type -> type.getDbValue().equals(value))
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
        }
    }
```

Таблица создавалась вот так:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS image
(
    catalog_num_code varchar(10),
    type             varchar(1),
    size             varchar(1),
    content          bytea not null,
    modify_at        timestamp,
    primary key (catalog_num_code, type, size)
);
```

При попытке сохранить новый объект Image получаю:

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = integer
Подсказка: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Позиция: 252

Как я понимаю, по умолчанию перечисление воспринимается как @Enumerated(value = EnumType.ORDINAL) и соответственно в БД летит целое число вместо строки.
Конвертеры не отрабатывают вообще, ставлю дебаг на методы конвертера, программа там не идёт. Что я упустил??

Answer (score 0):

Собственно, надо было почитать джавадок конвертера. Цитирую:

*Note that **Id attributes**, version attributes, relationship attributes, and attributes explicitly annotated as Enumerated or Temporal (or designated as such via XML) will not be converted.*

Как раз мой случай, когда оба перечисления являются частью составного ключа и помечены аннотацией @Id. Либо менять структуру сущности, либо смириться и сделать некрасивое перечисление.